# Remove adjacent duplicates from the string in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, duplicates

Let's say I have an input String as "aaabbaccd". I need to design a program which remove all the adjacent duplicates from my output. So taking the example of above string, the output would be :
1. First output that I would get after removing adjacent duplicates would be "aad" (Removed aabbcc from my input).
2. In the second pass, it would remove aa from my string and make my output as "d".

So far, what I could design the below code :

```
String input="aaabbaccd";

    String[] arr=input.split("");

    int n=arr.length;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if(i==arr.length-1) {
            if(arr[i-1].equals(arr[i])) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(arr[i]+ "");
                break;
            }
        }
        if(arr[i].equals(arr[i+1])) {
            i=i+1;
            continue;
        }
        if(!arr[i].equals(arr[i+1])) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]+ "");
        }
    }
```

The problem with this code is that it gives me output as aad. I cannot comprehend how to do the second pass on my code. Maybe recursion is something that I need to implement in this code. Please help me how to implement recursion in this code.

Comment: And your code is?

Comment: Besides the lack of code, I don't think you even described the algorithm fully or in a clear fashion. At least show us what is supposed to be happening here.

Comment: have added my code. Please let me know if anymore information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

One lazy alternative is to use regexp for it, where the `(.)` part matches any character and saving it, and the `\\1` references back to that match. I have added recursion to continue to apply the removal until string is no longer modified:

```
public String removeDuplicates(String original)
{
    String reduced = original.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "");

    if(reduced.equals(original))
        // No more duplicates, return original string
        return original;
    else
        // Duplicates were removed, continue recursion...
        return removeDuplicates(reduced);
}
```

The behaviour is verified with:

```
@Test
public void testIt()
{
    assertThat(removeDuplicates("aaabbaccd"), is("d"));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, could you also help me implement recursion in my above code ?

Comment: Is recursion a required part of the solution?

Comment: Not exactly, however, I would want to learn recursion through this code. Any other solution apart from recursion or regex that you could think of ?

Comment: Will be waiting for it.. :) would be a lot of help if you could use my code only in recursion..

Comment: In order to recurse on it in your original solution, you need to build a new intermediate String, not only print the characters... Try applying the same pattern I have used but replacing the original.replaceAll with your own method...

Comment: as far as I understand, reduced in your code is the string that I will get after the first pass, and rest I should just follow your code, is it ?

Comment: as per your recursion condition, recursion wills top when reduced will be equal to original, however I dont think we ll encounter this case in my string. So then when will this stop ?

Comment: First question, yes! Second question: When you reduce "aaabbaaccd" you get "aad". That one reduces to "d". But "d" will reduce to "d" and it is time to break the recursion, or you will end up with infinite recursion (well, not infinite, but it will run until you run out of stack, and then it will fail)...

Comment: perfect..!! that was a really great explanation. was able to complete my code..let me just publish my code as well. thanks for your help..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input="aaabbaccd";
        removeDupe(input);


    }

    public static void removeDupe(String input) {
        String[] arr=input.split("");

        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        int n=arr.length;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            if(i==arr.length-1) {
                if(arr.length==1) {
                    sb.append(arr[i]);
                    break;
                }
                if(arr[i-1].equals(arr[i])) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    sb.append(arr[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(arr[i].equals(arr[i+1])) {
                i=i+1;
                continue;
            }
            if(!arr[i].equals(arr[i+1])) {
                sb.append(arr[i]);
            }
        }

        //System.out.println(sb);

        if(sb.toString().equals(input)) {
            System.out.println(sb);
        }
        else {
            removeDupe(sb.toString());
        }


    }
```

Comment: I would recommend using StringBuilder not StringBuffer, StringBuilder isn't synchronized and is faster.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following one liner?

`(new LinkedHashSet<Character>("aaabbaccd".chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i).collect(Collectors.toList()))).stream().map(e -> e.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining());`

Answer (score 0):

I used StringBuilder class to store string and used StringBuilder's `replace()` method to remove Adjacent char.

This statement: `str.replace(i,i+2,"")` will actually ***delete*** adjacent chars.

The core logic is written in a static method named `remove()`. Note the point that I called the `remove()` method more than once i.e. str.length()/2 times. Because to remove Adjacent pair in new string we got after calling `remove()` each time.

```
public class RemoveDupl12{           
 public static StringBuilder remove(StringBuilder  str){    

   for( int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++ )

    {
        if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(i+1))
        { 
            str.replace(i,i+2,"");
            i++;
        }
    }
    return str;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder("daaabbad");

     for(int i=str.length()/2;i>0;i--)
     str=remove(str);

     if(str.length()==0)
         System.out.println("Final output=empty string"+str);

     else
         System.out.println("Final output="+str);
}}
```